# Random (super long) horizontal scroll bar only in Firefox/

Tags: css, firefox, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

As the title boasts, I'm encountering a rather strange problem with Firefox where it's giving my site a very long horizontal scroll bar and I have no idea why.

I tried going through and disabling every width:100% I could find, but nothing changed from that.

So I come to you, the overflowing stack of knowledge, for aid.

The website: http://demo28.abcguide.com/

I know there's a few other things on the site that seem broken, it's still in development phases currently, all I actually need help with is this horizontal scrollbar problem.

Thanks in advance for any help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input id="res-submit">` has a `text-indent: 9999em` style.  That seems to cause the overflow (probably by about 9990em or so).